# using only css how to select second level li

Tags: css

I need to select the second level li and change color to red then select third level li by themselves and set to blue. Any help?

```
    <title>Warehouse</title>
    <style>
      /* Write your CSS solution here */
      ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child{
          font-weight: bold;
      }
      ul:nth-of-type(1) > ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child{
          font-style: italic;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>first level
        <ul>
          <li>second level
            <ul>
              <li>third level</li>
              <li>third level</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li>4th level
            <ul>
              <li>5th level</li>
              <li>5th level</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expected this to select the second level li but it did not

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the **[child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)** to specifically target the children and grandchildren with `li > ul > li` and `li > ul > li > ul > li`:

```css
ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul:nth-of-type(1)>ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child {
  font-style: italic;
}

li > ul > li {
  color: red;
}

li > ul > li > ul > li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>first level
      <ul>
        <li>second level
          <ul>
            <li>third level</li>
            <li>third level</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>4th level
          <ul>
            <li>5th level</li>
            <li>5th level</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Even though the grandchildren will be coloured `red` initially, they will have their colour overridden to `blue` due to increased **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**.

If by 'level' you mean the text representations rather than the DOM hierarchy, you can chain the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class and `:nth-of-type(2)` to 'reapply' the grandchildren's **default** color of `black` with the selector `li > ul:nth-of-type(2) > li > ul > li`:

```css
ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul:nth-of-type(1) > ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child {
  font-style: italic;
}

li > ul:first-of-type > li {
  color: red;
}

li > ul:first-of-type > li > ul > li {
  color: blue;
}

li > ul:nth-of-type(2) > li > ul > li {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>first level
      <ul>
        <li>second level
          <ul>
            <li>third level</li>
            <li>third level</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>4th level
          <ul>
            <li>5th level</li>
            <li>5th level</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Again, this has increased specificity over the selector that sets them to `red`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `>` selects **direct children**.

Using **child combinators** it must looks like this:

```
ul:nth-of-type(1) > li > ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child {}
```

But you could simplify this most of the times to

```
ul:nth-of-type(1) ul:nth-of-type(1):first-child {}
```

But in both cases beware when adding more depth to the tree... these selectors will find all "pairs" across all levels ;)

I recommend you further reading at the MDN docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator